# phpmyadmin imported table from mysql workbench can't work

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm still new to all of this so please do guild me and teach me if I'm wrong.

Currently I am working on creating a database on MySQL Workbench. There is one table that I have created that uses the following configuration:

Table Collation: utf8 - default collation

Engine: InnoDB

This is the same configuration that I have used in all my tables. In this particular table I have set 3 primary keys which are:

key1 varchar(256)

key2 varchar(256)

key3 char(30)

and it was created successfully. However when I try to import this table into my phpMyAdmin it gets an error saying 
"#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes" 
the configuration that I used in phpMyAdmin is as followed:

Storage Engine: InnoDB

Collation: utf8 - bin

I understand that the error only occur when the total length of the key is over the max length set by InnoDB but I'm curious why this error didn't occur when I was creating the table in MySQL Workbench and only in phpMyAdmin.

Is there a way to fix this or overcome this problem?
Cause I have search around this website already and I haven't seen a fix for this problem. Please help me.

EDIT: I didn't change the size of the key is because I need it to be the same with another database that I'm using.